# Screen display stretched horizontally after ubuntu update, can no longer see whole screen

Tags: drivers, display, display-resolution

I'm quite puzzled about how to solve this.

I have Ubuntu 16.04, a Lenovo T420s laptop.

I updated recently, and when I restarted my computer, my screen was stretched out twice as wide. This occurs even before Ubuntu boots, on the Thinkpad start up screen. Below is one example where I was trying to run Ubuntu in recovery mode.

[image: Stretched screen example]

I've tried:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

There was no change.

Results of `lspci | grep VGA`:

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)

When I boot into Windows, I can see the full screen, but there's a black strip maybe 1 inch wide on the right side.

In Ubuntu, when I try to adjust the "Displays" property in "Settings" it says, "Could not get screen information."

In Ubuntu, when I try to adjust the "Displays" property in "System Settings", it doesn't show anything strange, it looks normal, see screenshot below.

[image: Display setting screenshot]

How else can I try to solve this problem?

Since it shows up on the Thinkpad start up screen before Ubuntu boots, it makes me think it's a hardware problem...but then it's funny that it appeared only after I rebooted my computer.  And it's also funny that when I boot into Windows it doesn't have the exact same problem.

UPDATE:
I've also tried updating the Intel Graphics drivers by downloading the [Intel Graphics Installer](https://www.techzim.co.zw/2017/06/tuning-intel-graphics-card-ubuntu-16-04/) and installing it:

```
dpkg -i intel-graphics-update-tool_2.0.2_amd64.deb
```

I also tried every display option in the bios boot up menu.
I tried downloading Ubuntu 18.04 onto an USB and booting from USB - the stretched screen remains the same.

There is one brief moment where my screen reverts back to normal, when I'm shutting down, there's one brief flash of a terminal screen with white letters on a black background in a normal aspect ratio.  Otherwise everything is still stretched!

Any other ideas out there?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was a hardware failure - I swapped hard drives with another computer. The screen problem stayed with the computer and not the hard drive.  Also, the laptop could still display correctly on an external monitor,even though its own screen was still displaying strangely.

Perhaps there's something wrong with the graphics card, but on Lenovo T420s, it looks like it's a soldered component and not easily replaceable:  [link](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-T400-T500-and-newer-T/T420-Graphics-Upgrade/td-p/2099453)

Time to scrap my laptop for parts...